# Run asp.net mvc application from linqpad or console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linqpad

How can i start and get ActionResult from some actions of my mvc application use only Linqpad or console application?

I know i can create MvcApplication class instanse:

```
var mvcApplication = new Web.MvcApplication();
```

then create controller:

```
var homeController = new Web.Controllers.HomeController();
```

even run controller's action

```
homeController.Index()
```

but it returns nothing. What is lifecycle of mvc application? Which methods i shoud call to emulate web request from user?

EDIT

---

Here some good posts about ASP.NET MVC lifecycle, but unfortunally i cannot resolve my problem yet

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/

Comment: May I inquire as to what the goal of such a feat would be?

Comment: @Kenneth K The main purpose is to make testing and bug fixing more easy. Ofcourse i can use unit test but they havent such powerfull output methods as Dump in Linqpad.

Comment: @Kenneth K And another reason is better understanding how asp.net mvc application actually works. When you trying do it by your own hands it is much better then just read any article.

Comment: I was just confirming that you weren't wanting to look at the raw requests/responses, something you could do with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp). It sounds like you're wanting to get a bit deeper than that  :)

Comment: @Kenneth K. Thanks, i know about Fiddler but my problem on another side :)

Comment: See [Building Testable ASP.NET MVC Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942838.aspx#id0420144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, and might be answered elsewhere, but in a project I am working on we can debug Controller Actions with Linqpad and get returned values.

Briefly, you need to tell Linqpad to return something:

```cs
var result = homeController.Index();
result.Dump();
```

You may also need to mock your context and attach visual studio as the debugger.

Full code snippet:

```cs
void Main()
{       
    using(var svc = new  CrmOrganizationServiceContext(new CrmConnection("Xrm"))) 
    {
        DummyIdentity User = new DummyIdentity();

        using (var context = new XrmDataContext(svc)) 
        {
            // Attach the Visual Studio debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            // Instantiate the Controller to be tested
            var controller = new HomeController(svc);
            // Instantiate the Context, this is needed for IPrincipal User
            var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(); 

            controllerContext.HttpContext = new DummyHttpContext();
            controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext; 

            // Test the action
            var result = controller.Index();
            result.Dump();
        }
    }             
}

// Below is the Mocking classes used to sub in Context, User, etc.
public class DummyHttpContext:HttpContextBase {
    public override IPrincipal User {get {return new  DummyPrincipal();}}
}

public class DummyPrincipal : IPrincipal 
{
    public bool IsInRole(string role) {return role == "User";} 
    public IIdentity Identity {get {return new DummyIdentity();}}
}

public class DummyIdentity : IIdentity 
{
    public string AuthenticationType { get {return "?";} }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get {return true;}}
    public string Name { get {return "sampleuser@email.com";} }
}
```

You should get prompted to select a debugger, select the instance of Visual Studio with your app built.

We have a specific set up for MVC-CRM so this may not work for everyone, but hopefully this will help someone else out.